# Как запустить стороннюю программу с конфигурацией

Tags: c#

хочу запустить стороннюю программу с конфигурацией. Вот пример запуска с конфигурацией:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Механотроника\Конфигуратор-МТ\Configurator-MT.exe" "-interface:eth|192.168.11.22|503" -bfpo:"D:\БФПО-152-КСЗ-01_26.sth" -pmk:"D:\БФПО-152-КСЗ-01_26.sth_a" -connect:true -download_pmk:true

Как это сделать?

Comment: А сторонняя программа это поддерживает?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/18.1.php в самом низу показано как запускать